# If an object inherit from an abstract class that inherite from an interface will the object inherit from the interface?

Tags: c#, ioc-container

If an object inherit from an abstract class that inherite from an interface will the object inherit from the interface ?

Will this interface can be used with Dependency Injection Container ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does implement that interface and since this is true it can be injected as a dependency.

Here is a quick test that proves the interface implementation:

```
using System;

interface IParent {}
abstract class Parent : IParent {}

class Example : Parent
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new Example() is IParent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I consider interface as a kind of contract. Since the abstract class inherite from the interface, it is surely demanded to implement the functions of the interface. And the object (in fact the class of it) is demanded to override the abstract function of the abstract class. 
In my opinion, this pattern is only suitable for stable interface or abstract class. Cause once there was change to the contract of the interface or abstract class, that would be a disaster. Oops~~, you screw the build!

I prefer use the virtual class for base class and make the functions virtual, so you can override them in the subclasses as same as the interface/abstractclass solution, and new overloads can be added easily as well.